# TextView link to new layout view Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to understand how to have it so that when users click a specific TextView that they are linked to a new layout, in this example, signup.

ie.,

```
<!--Not have account? Signup-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noAccountTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_account"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        />
```

The layout file is activity_sign_up.xml, - i'm used to react and html etc, so this is all a bit new to me :) thanks!

Comment: For that you can use ClickableSpan and make particular part of textview clickable.

Answer (score 4):

You should check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity). But basically, what you need is an intent. So, you want to do something like this

```
noAccountTv.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,ActivitySignUp::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

You will have to send an intent to the activity class that uses the layout file activity_sign_up.xml